# Is it possible to add multiple location for a single node and solr can show all location for a search?

Tags: solr, geolocation, drupal-7

The scenario: let's say you have a product in multiple location and when you search for the product (not for location) you should see all locations. In Drupal you can use multivalue fields for locations (but in solr I don't know). When index the product whit solr you should not send it, let's say, 3 time (and hold it in your DB 3 times) just once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In sor also, you can have multivalued fields.

```
<field name="location" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

So the location would be multivalued entries with a Single Product entry in Solr.
The locations would be returned with the product document, and you can filter, facet on the location information as required.