# Solr LatLonType multivalued=true, to sort document by nearest one of multiple points

Tags: java, solr, lucene, geospatial

The official Solr documentation were clear about [this issue](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch#geodist_-_The_distance_function):

> Fields using LatLonType must be single valued (i.e. multiValued="false")

The question is why there is such limitation, and how it's possible to extend Solr to support this feature. Any tips would be useful.

**Problem Details**: I have a solr core that contains multiple documents (ex: place) with multiple location for each. Solr does not yet support AFAIK storing multivalued `LatLonType`. I have to implement a solution for this, by creating a query function that maps the multiple lat/lng locations to the nearest one using a given center point parameter i.e. multivalued `geodist` function. But I need some tips for doing that, from any experienced solr/lucene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at: [Is it possible to add multiple location for a single node and solr can show all location for a search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169324/is-it-possible-to-add-multiple-location-for-a-single-node-and-solr-can-show-all) You can index multiple geolocation for a node, the problem is, when you search you will find just the first geolocation.